# Kinectisj: Issue where mouse trail remains(Layer issue)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, mouseevent, kineticjs

I am making a game as a selfstudy.

My objective is to have a trail after the mouse pointer.(Which works)
But,when i open on chrome and run it.
After a certain height and width,the trail stays on the canvas instead of being wiped off.
Can anyone help me with this?

Here's the fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/Frm27/4/
But please do try it on chrome or any browser,cause the issue is not on fiddle but the browser!

I have the following codes:

```
var LimitedArray = function (upperLimit) {
    var storage = [];

    // default limit on length if none/invalid supplied;
    upperLimit = +upperLimit > 0 ? upperLimit : 100;

    this.push = function (item) {
        storage.push(item);
        if (storage.length > upperLimit) {
            storage.shift();
        }
        return storage.length;
    };

    this.get = function (i) {
        return storage[i];
    };

    this.iterateItems = function (iterator) {
        var i, l = storage.length;
        if (typeof iterator !== 'function') { return; }
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            iterator(storage[i]);
        }
    };
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var tail = new LimitedArray(50);

    var i = 0, j = 0;
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
        listening: true
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
        listening: true
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var player = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: 20,
        y: 20,
        radius: 6,
        fill: 'cyan',
        stroke: 'black',
        draggable: true
    });

    layer.add(player);


    // move the circle with the mouse
    stage.getContent().addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
        layer.removeChildren();
        layer.add(player);
        player.setPosition(stage.getPointerPosition());
        var obj = {
            x: stage.getPointerPosition().x,
            y: stage.getPointerPosition().y
        };

        tail.push(obj);
        var arr = [];
        tail.iterateItems(function (p) {
            arr.push(p.x, p.y);
        });
        var line = new Kinetic.Line({
        points: arr,
        stroke: 'white',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        lineCap: 'round',
        lineJoin: 'round'
      });
        layer.add(line);
        layer.draw();
    });
    stage.add(layer);
});
```

Here's the html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Collision Detection</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style=" background:#000; margin:auto; float:left;"></div>
        <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/kinetic-v5.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/main_kinetic.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and css:

```
html {
    color:#000;
    background:#222222;
}
a {
    cursor:pointer;
    list-style: none;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
html, body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, code, form, fieldset, legend, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#container {
    background:#000;
    margin:auto;
    cursor:none;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Its A Layer issue.. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Might be an O/S issue.  Works as expected for me on Win8 using any of IE11,FF26 & Chrome32.  I see a circle with tail.  The tail gets much longer if you drag the mouse faster (because dragpoints are further apart). The tail gets shorter if you drag the mouse slower (because dragpoints are closer together).

Comment: Does it work even in the extremes of the window?

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same issue as you in a project I am working on.

I am able to reproduce your problem in Chrome 34.0.1847.116 m but not IE11 (See "Problem fiddle").

It seems to be a bug in KineticJS 4.5.3, as Moving to KineticJS 5.1.0 seems to fix it (See "Fixed fiddle").

[Problem fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntN3u/)

[Fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6j68N/)

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var player = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    radius: 6,
    fill: 'cyan',
    stroke: 'black',
    draggable: true
});

layer.add(player);
stage.add(layer);

// move the circle with the mouse
stage.getContent().addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
    player.setPosition(stage.getPointerPosition());        
    layer.draw();
});
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @Chaos Actually, I think this is an answer... Paul had the same problem, this is his solution.

Comment: Sorry yes, I was answering the question :)